# How to setup Clusters in Marklogic via xquery?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am new to marklogic and I am trying to setup clusters in marklogic. I am able to setup cluster using the admin interface. But my requirement is to setup cluster via xquery code. I have marklogic installed in 3 instances.

Comment: I highly recommend using a deployment tool to do this, rather than trying to reinvent this wheel from scratch. `ml-gradle` as recommended by Ganesh below is really your best option.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the option of using a tool like Gradle, you should look at ml-gradle - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle. It abstracts a lot of coding for you and lets you create a cluster with the databases, forests and app servers you need in a configurable manner. And you can also create users, roles and other artifacts using ml-gradle. You can even deploy your modules using ml-gradle. I would urge you to look at that before you try and code this via XQuery.

One other option is to use the REST Management APIs, but you should try ml-gradle first. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

[ml-gradle](https://developer.marklogic.com/code/ml-gradle/) is definitely the preferred tool, but if you are unable to use it, MarkLogic also has a [Scripting Administrative Tasks](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api) guide, which includes [Scripting Cluster Management](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/admin-api/cluster).  The guide includes sample curl calls, and bash scripts that can be used to create a cluster.